# Connection Lifetime with urllib3 Library

Tags: python, locust, urllib3

I’m using Locust for load testing and I’m trying to implement a connection lifetime such that connections in a connection pool are closed on the client side after a certain amount of time has passed since the connection’s creation. This functionality exists in C# with [PooledConnectionLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.pooledconnectionlifetime?view=net-7.0).

I've been unable to replicate the connection lifetime functionality with the connection library that Locust uses, urllib3. I have a client script that uses HttpUser. I’ve not had success after getting the HttpUser to use a PoolManager subclass. The subclass uses HttpConnection and HttpsConnection subclasses that have overridden methods which attempt to implement the connection lifetime functionality. It seems like the subclasses are not even used, as they don't produce any logs when the Locust client is running.

Is there a way to add the connection lifetime functionality to urllib3, or another solution that can be used?

Edit: My attempt to implement the functionality leveraged the `conn.timeout.get_connect_duration()` [method](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Timeout.get_connect_duration). I'm not sure if `start_connect()` is called only on the first time `_make_request` is used, or every time it's taken out of the pool.

Answer (score 1):

The package `urllib3` has a `Timeout` object which can be assigned to a connection pool to force closure of long-running connections.

#### Example

---

*Example from official docs*

```py
timeout = Timeout(connect=2.0, read=7.0)
http = PoolManager(timeout=timeout)
response = http.request('GET', 'http://example.com/')
```

#### Locust Implementation

---

From the `locust` source code it appears that `HttpUser` has an optional parameter `pool_manager`. This parameter defaults to `None` but can be assigned a `PoolManager` object as defined by `urllib3`.

#### Docs

---

- [**urllib3.util.Timeout**](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.util.html#urllib3.util.Timeout)
- [**urllib3.PoolManager**](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/urllib3.poolmanager.html)
- [**Locust HttpUser**](https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/locust/user/users.py)

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
The `timeout`'s `connect` parameter is for "maximum amount of time (in seconds) to wait for a connection attempt to a server to succeed." The number of connections is not important, and it is assumed that the server is always responsive and able to be connected to. Therefore, the `read` parameter is also not relevant to my use case.

Comment: The client script I'm using assigns the custom `Pool_Manager` to an `HttpUser`. I gave the `HttpConnection` subclasses to the pool manager by changing the [`pool_classes_by_scheme`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/socks.html#urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSProxyManager.pool_classes_by_scheme) parameter of `Pool_Manager` ([Location in code](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/main/src/urllib3/poolmanager.py#L159)). However, that doesn't seem to have worked because there's no indication that the connection subclasses are being used, even after adding log statements.